# count of all Sobjects Record in salesforce org

Tags: count

I wanted a query to get data volume of all objects in sales-force. 
May be a count of all object's record at once. I know I can do it by Count in workbench. But I have to do it for all objects. So is there any generic way of doing it for all objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you aren't concerned about having this information available in code, you can get this information by going to the setup menu -> System Overview (3rd link from the top on the left-side menu) -> click on the number listed under 'Data Storage'

For url-hackers, it's `salesforce.com/setup/org/orgstorageusage.jsp?id=<your orgId>`

Under the 'Data Storage' header, this page shows you a count of how many records of each object (standard and custom) the org contains, as well as the amount of storage space each object is consuming, sorted by storage space used